# How to get offline users in a chat room in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, multiuserchat

We have setup ejabberd on an Ubuntu server and we want to fetch all offline users in a room to send push notification.

How we can get them from database?

What will be configuration for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As defined in XEP-0045 MultiUser Chat, chat room in XMPP are presence-based. I means that to [join a room you send a presence packet to the room](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter). When you disconnect, the server sends a [presence unavailable to the room so that you leave it](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#exit). You can also send a presence unavailable to leave it "manually", but still stay connected.

It means that by definition, there is not offline users in an XMPP chat room.

Comment: Do we have any hook as like offline_message_hook for single chat, do we have anything for room chat?